# IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings doesn't get stored

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

i am trying to retaing the last date that i have visited my app, and after looking around i came up with this init in the App.xaml.cs:

```
appSettings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
             try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("INIT LAST MODIFIED " + (string)appSettings["lastModifiedDate"]);
            }
            catch (KeyNotFoundException)
            {
                appSettings.Add("lastModifiedDate","");
            }
```

The logic is that if try to display a value that hasn't been added (the first run), i get an exception KeyNotFoundException. This is all good.. The problem is when i restart my application, the code still calls the exception(as if the variable isn't set). A have some questions if anyone could answer:

1) Does the app setting survive after an app close?(i understood they do)

2) Does the simulator store this values or not?

If any of these issues are ok, do you figure out what is the problem?

Comment: You could make a call to `appSettings.Contains("lastModifiedDate")` rather than relying on an exception to control application logic.

Comment: tried it, didn't work.. as @Rich points out, i ommited ".Save()"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
appSettings.Save();
```

There's the line you need!

Oh - and yes, the emulator will store the settings, UNTIL you either:

1. Rebuild the project
2. Close the emulator and reload it.

Every time you reload the emulator, it starts fresh, as if it had never run before.  And when you rebuild a project (not just build, but click Build|Rebuild), it will remove it from the emulator.  It will do the same on an actual device.  So anytime you want to have it so that it is like the first time you run the app, rebuild, whether it is on phone or emulator.